# Enthusiast/Fanatic Badges have to be from one computer?

Tags: bug, status-norepro

So I was testing a theory, because I was sure I should have at least the 30 days and probably have the 100 days and I found that the days counting only seems to be from 1 computer. If on Monday I do it on my work PC only, then on Tuesday on my home PC, when I login from my WOrk PC on Wednesday it says 1 consecutive day again, when it should say 3. Shouldn't this be tracked better or at least documented that you need to keep your streak on 1 machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't correct; all that matters is that we see a user account. What computer it is from, is irrelevant.

Just realize that our day is tracked in UTC so you must visit the site *in a non-trivial way* each 24 hour UTC period.

Answer (score 0):

You can log in from different machines - I certainly do.

Some things to bear in mind:

1. The Stack Overflow "day" is 00:00 **UTC** to 23:59 **UTC** (or 00:01 to 00:00) so if you're not in the UK you could very easily login one morning and then the next afternoon but miss a day.
2. You need to do more than just log in and view the home page. I don't exactly what triggers a "visit", whether its a refresh or visiting another page, but I've missed days by only viewing the home page.

Comment: I bet you two are right, I just looked up UTC and it I can see where I might have done this exact scenario. Like I told Jeff I will run tests with UTC in mind. Thanks.